# Return from incompatible pointer type C

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

I'm still trying to get to grips with pointers,structures and malloc in C. I'm trying to impliment a hash table using linked lists. I'm getting a return from incompatible pointer type error when I try to compile:

```
struct Mlist_head{
    struct Mlist_node *head;
    struct Mlist_node *tail;
};

struct MList {
    int size;
    struct Mlist_head hashtable[HASHSIZE];
};

MList *ml_create(void){ 

    struct MList *m;
    struct Mlist_head *h;
    int i;

    if ((m = (struct MList *)malloc(sizeof(struct MList))) != NULL){
        if ((h = (struct Mlist_head *)malloc(sizeof(struct Mlist_head))) != NULL) { 
            for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++) {
                h = &(m->hashtable[i]);
                h->head = NULL;
                h->tail = NULL;
            }
            printf("worked");
            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there could be other errors in here (possibly semantic) but one thing at a time :)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, one of the "other errors" is that you don't return anything at all if the allocation fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MList *ml_create(void){
```

Should be

```
struct MList *ml_create(void){
```

Comment: You can also avoid having to explicitly tell the compiler it is a struct every time by using typedef, declare your struct like: `typedef struct MList {
int size;
struct Mlist_head hashtable[HASHSIZE];
} MList;`

Comment: My header file has the line: typedef struct mlist MList; I still need to include the struct tag before the funtion is declared in the C file?

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `struct` declaration doesn't automatically introduce a new type. You need to use the `struct` keyword with the name you gave the structure (which is technically called the struct's tag):

```
struct MList *ml_create(void);
```

You can work around this by defining a new type name, using the `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef struct Mlist_head MList;
```

Now you can do:

```
MList ml_create(void);
```

Also:

- In C, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).
- Consider using `sizeof *h` rather than `sizeof (struct Mlist_head)`; it's shorter and less error-prone.

For these last two points, compare your code:

```
if ((m = (struct MList *)malloc(sizeof(struct MList))) != NULL){
```

with this, which is how I would write it:

```
if ((m = malloc(sizeof *m)) != NULL) {
```

To me, the latter is much much easier to read since it has less noise, and it's also safer since it doesn't repeat the type name. If the type of the `m` pointer later changes, my verrsion is still 100% correct.